# How can I do this design in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to apply this design in Bootstrap

[image]

My try:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="p-2 n-p-l-r">
            <div class="toast fade show" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" data-toggle="toast">
                <div class="toast-header" style="justify-content: center;">
                    <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/product/2x/photos_96dp.png" alt="brand-logo" height="12" width="12" class="mr-1" />
                    <strong>...</strong>
                    <small></small>
                </div>
                <div class="toast-body  text-center">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div> <!--end toast-->
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="p-2 n-p-l-r">
            <div class="toast fade show" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" data-toggle="toast">
                <div class="toast-header" style="justify-content: center;">
                    <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/product/2x/photos_96dp.png" alt="brand-logo" height="12" width="12" class="mr-1" />
                    <strong>...</strong>
                    <small></small>
                </div>
                <div class="toast-body  text-center">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div> <!--end toast-->
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="p-2 n-p-l-r">
            <div class="toast fade show" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" data-toggle="toast">
                <div class="toast-header" style="justify-content: center;">
                    <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/product/2x/photos_96dp.png" alt="brand-logo" height="12" width="12" class="mr-1" />
                    <strong>...</strong>
                    <small></small>
                </div>
                <div class="toast-body  text-center">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div> <!--end toast-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-6 mt-2 mx-auto">
        <div class="image-flip" >
            <div class="mainflip flip-0">
                <div class="frontside">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body text-center">
                            <p><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/280x280_RS/4b/09/50/4b095022924fd658cf71ecafc3974710.jpg" class="img-fluid"/></p>
                            <h4 class="card-title">...</h4>
                            <p class="card-text">...</p>
                            <p class="card-text">...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

<div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="p-2 n-p-l-r">
            <div class="toast fade show" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" data-toggle="toast">
                <div class="toast-header" style="justify-content: center;">
                    <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/product/2x/photos_96dp.png" alt="brand-logo" height="12" width="12" class="mr-1" />
                    <strong>...</strong>
                    <small></small>
                </div>
                <div class="toast-body  text-center">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div> <!--end toast-->
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="p-2 n-p-l-r">
            <div class="toast fade show" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" data-toggle="toast">
                <div class="toast-header" style="justify-content: center;">
                    <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/product/2x/photos_96dp.png" alt="brand-logo" height="12" width="12" class="mr-1" />
                    <strong>...</strong>
                    <small></small>
                </div>
                <div class="toast-body  text-center">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div> <!--end toast-->
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="p-2 n-p-l-r">
            <div class="toast fade show" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" data-toggle="toast">
                <div class="toast-header" style="justify-content: center;">
                    <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/product/2x/photos_96dp.png" alt="brand-logo" height="12" width="12" class="mr-1" />
                    <strong>...</strong>
                    <small></small>
                </div>
                <div class="toast-body  text-center">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div> <!--end toast-->
        </div>
    </div>
```

What I get:

[image]

How can I do it? It would be very helpful if you could solve this problem for me.

Comment: You could always just use CSS directly, without using Bootstrap's predefined classes.

Comment: Stack Overflow is about helping everyone, not just you. So of course it would be helpful to you if we spent our time solving the problem for you, but how would it help anyone else?